# Why does bash output data instead of executing, when a script is piped?

Tags: bash, apt, pipe

I'm running the following script on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get purge -y nginx
apt-get install -y nginx

date
```

When I run it like `cat /tmp/script | bash`, apt-get starts installing, then "date" is printed (not the actual date, but the command name), then the remaining apt-get output is printed.

If however I run the script like `/tmp/script`, it works as expected: printing the date after apt-get finished.

Why does this happen and how can I force bash to work when being piped to the same way it does when invoked directly?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that (with other commands). What happens if you put `echo foo #` at the beginning of the `apt-get` lines? Have a look at the output of `od -t c -t x1 /tmp/script`. Are there only newlines or maybe `\r`s, too?

Comment: @HaukeLaging, with echoes it works as expected. There are no `\r` symbols. BTW my bash version is 4.3.11 and this is the default ubuntu 14 image provided by AWS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to close (or otherwise redirect) the standard input of the individual commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get purge -y nginx <&-
apt-get install -y nginx <&-

date
```

Otherwise subsequent line are fed to the commands.

Comment: I now get infinite `E: Write error - write (14: Bad address)` messages

Comment: @Fluffy try redirecting in from `/dev/null`, instead. Oh, wait. "Write error"?

Comment: Yes, either way, `< /dev/null` helped, thanks